# Rails form multi select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, multi-select

I have a rails form which has intermediate_points field that corresponds to a text column in rails.

In model.rb

```
  serialize :intermediate_points
```

In controller.rb

```
def set_params
   params.require(:modela).permit(:intermediate_points)
end
```

In view.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :intermediate_points %>
    <%= f.select :intermediate_points, @intermediate_points, {}, multiple: true %>
</div>
```

The option appears as a multi select field. But I am not able to select multiple options in the view. How can I make the view to select multiple options?

Comment: Are you not able to select multiple options OR not able to save them?

Comment: Not able to select multiple options in the UI

Comment: How do you select them?

Comment: Its a multiselect scroll box. I just click one after other. and the last selected option is what I get in response

Comment: _"I just click one after other."_ - Click OR Cmd + Click / Ctrl + Click?

Comment: oops.. ctrl + click works.... Thanks..

Comment: I think you will also need @Nimish's answer to allow the selected options to be saved in your controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any issue in you view code.

What I would like to know is what is the output of `@ intermediate_points`

As it is a multiselect, therefore, you have to permit your params correctly.

In your controller, use below syntax to permit an array

```
def set_params
   params.require(:modela).permit(intermediate_points: [])
end
```